# How to trash some file from a different directory without typing the directory each times?

Tags: command-line, git

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    Assignment_3/Apriori/bodon_trie.pdf
    deleted:    Assignment_3/Apriori/farhanSir.pdf
    deleted:    Assignment_3/Apriori/output.txt~
    deleted:    Assignment_4/Comparision/report.aux
    deleted:    Assignment_4/Comparision/report.log
    deleted:    Assignment_4/FPGrowth/FPGrowth.class
    deleted:    Assignment_4/FPGrowth/FPGrowthApplication.class
    deleted:    Assignment_4/FPGrowth/Node.class
    deleted:    Assignment_4/FPGrowth/Result.class
```

This is the output of `git status`.
I want to delete this from git cache using `git rm --cache Assignment_3/Apriori/boden_trie.pdf ?/farhanSir.pdf` I don't want to type `Assignment_3/Apriori` for each file.

Comment: Suffice to first cd into Assignment_3/Apriori?

Comment: @vanadium I want to do the job from current directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Bash brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
git rm --cache Assignment_3/Apriori/{boden_trie.pdf,farhanSir.pdf}
```

Comment: you can further shorten this by factoring out the extension: `…/{boden_trie,farhanSir}.pdf`

Answer (score -1):

You can install bleachbit and it has an option for deleting files or folders.

```
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
```

Comment: How would you use it exactly?

Comment: It has GUI that allows you to select specific files or folders to delete. This makes it so you don't have to type every single file name or folder name. You just select the files to delete and delete them. It also allows you to 'shred' or 'overwrite files to hide contents. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyLb6ZATdkc